# Dimension of the kernel of a defective matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If a matrix $A$ is defective i.e. there doesn't exist a basis eigenvectors of $A$ that are all linearly independent. Does this imply that the $\text{dim}\left(ker\left( A \right) \right) > 0$? i.e. The dimension of the image-space is less than the dimension of the domain?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Being defective does not imply that the kernel is nonzero. Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Your definition of defective is a little unusual.  I use the definition of defective being that the eigenvectors do not span the entire space.  Your definition is confusing because you can often have linearly dependent eigenvectors without being defective, just take an eigenvector and scale it.

Comment: OK I guess I should have made it more clear that I meant you could not have a basis of linearly independent eigenvectors. So I think I was trying to express what you're saying @MichaelBurr.

Comment: Thank you; I will remove the no-longer-relevant comments.

Comment: Another example is a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right)$; if $\theta\neq n\pi$, then the matrix has no eigenvectors at all, but is always nonsingular.